Why this MQTT callback hangs the system?
I'm using Arduino IDE with SAMD21 based PLC and Ethernet shield. There is an external source of MQTT messages published to plc topic. Messages are 8 bytes long, consisting of int32 and float32. Printing the message content from messageReceived() callback works just fine. Adding any logic instead or after Serial.println() in the callback, causes the system to hang when it receives the message. Here is the minimum code example:
#include <P1AM.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <MQTT.h>

using namespace std;

#define HOST_NAME "WIZnet"
uint8_t macPLC[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};
uint8_t ipPLC [] = {192, 168, 0, 41};  
char    broker[] = "192.168.0.42";

EthernetClient ethernet;
MQTTClient mqtt;
int n = 0;


void messageReceived(MQTTClient *client, char topic[], char bytes[], int length) {
  if (length == 8) {
    int32_t commandID = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&bytes[0]);
    float   commandArg = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&bytes[4]);

    Serial.println(commandID);
    Serial.println(commandArg);
    n += commandID;  // problem line
  }
  else
    Serial.println("wrong length!!!");
}


void setup() { // the setup routine runs once:
  Serial.begin(115200);  // USB serial for logging 

  while (!P1.init()) 
    delay(1); //Wait for Modules to Sign on   
  
  Ethernet.begin(macPLC, ipPLC);
  mqtt.begin(broker, ethernet);

  while (!mqtt.connect(broker)) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.println("\nConnected to MQTT broker.");
  mqtt.subscribe("plc", 2);
  mqtt.onMessageAdvanced(messageReceived);
  delay(1000);
}


void loop() {
  mqtt.loop();
  Serial.println(n++);
  delay(2000);
}

This will hang up. Commenting out the problem line will make it run just fine. What could be the reason?

The strict aliasing rule violation. Never do that w/o specific reasons int32_t commandID = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&bytes[0]); float   commandArg = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&bytes[4]);.

@3CxEZiVlQ My specific reason is that binary read from istringstream didn't seem to work. Is there another option than reinterpret_cast?

Look for "How do we Type Pun correctly?" in the answers of the linked post.

@3CxEZiVlQ Thank you, it very helpful. I ended up with `int32_t commandID;
float   commandArg;
memcpy(&commandID, &bytes[0], sizeof(commandID));
memcpy(&commandArg, &bytes[4], sizeof(commandArg));`


ARM architecture is very sensitive to such valuations.

probably an alignment issue, if bytes's address isn't a multiple of 4 you can't use it as an int pointer on ARM

@AlanBirtles Thanks. Is there any problem with the solution I posted in a comment above?

No, you can memcpy from arbitrary addresses
